# Issues after upgrading Ruby & Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rvm

I upgraded my Ruby to 2.1.2 & I upgraded Rails to 4.1.2.

I currently have 2 issues that I can't seem to get passed and they may be interconnected.

First, I get this error: `Could not find attr_encrypted-1.3.2 in any of the sources` when CLEARLY when I run `bundle install` it says `Using attr_encrypted (1.3.2)`.

Second, before this, I noticed that when I do `rails c` the version of Ruby is `2.0.0`, but `ruby --version` outputs `ruby 2.1.2p95` and `rvm lists` shows that I am using Ruby 2.1.2. Frustrating, and I think these issues may be interconnected.

`bundle install` does not fix it. Deleting my `Gemfile.lock` does not fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bet its spring again, caching your app.

```
spring stop
```

Edit 1
Spring is a rails application preloader. It caches the app, making running rails commands, task, tests etc. faster by saving rails load time. It's default since rails 4.1. Check your bin folder. There will be binstubs within. Open bin/rails and you'll see it loading spring which does the caching magic.

In 99% of the time rails will pick up your code changes. But this won't be the case on changing startup code like gem loading.

Comment: Wow. That worked. Do you mind putting in more detail. I'd love to know what happened.

Comment: Posted more details. This is like 100st time i see this happening